# trouble with new Core Audio API's iOS 8

Tags: avfoundation, core-audio, ios8

I'm trying to learn the new CoreAudio API's for iOS 8 and can't seem to generate any sound on my device.  I'm using the code from WWDC session 502 plus I thought it would be a good idea to start an audio session.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()


@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *error;
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];


AVAudioEngine *engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
AVAudioPlayerNode *player = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
[engine attachNode:player];

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"mySound" withExtension:@"aif"];
AVAudioFile *file = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:fileURL error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error getting audio file");
}

AVAudioMixerNode *mainMixer = [engine mainMixerNode];
// just to be safe
mainMixer.outputVolume = 1;
[engine connect:player to:mainMixer format:file.processingFormat];
[player scheduleFile:file atTime:nil completionHandler:nil];

if ([engine startAndReturnError:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"engine succsessful %@", error);
} else {
    NSLog(@"error starting engine: %@", error);
}
[player play];




return YES;
```

}

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`engine` is getting released before you hear anything. Add engine as a class member, so it doesn't get thrown away as soon as didFinishLaunching returns

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()
    AVAudioEngine *engine;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *error;
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];


engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
AVAudioPlayerNode *player = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
[engine attachNode:player];

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"mySound" withExtension:@"aif"];
AVAudioFile *file = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:fileURL error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error getting audio file");
}

AVAudioMixerNode *mainMixer = [engine mainMixerNode];
// just to be safe
mainMixer.outputVolume = 1;
[engine connect:player to:mainMixer format:file.processingFormat];
[player scheduleFile:file atTime:nil completionHandler:nil];

if ([engine startAndReturnError:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"engine succsessful %@", error);
} else {
    NSLog(@"error starting engine: %@", error);
}
[player play];

return YES;
}
```

The AVAudioSession is unnecessary.

Comment: I can) you save my day)